# Acesso restrito a arquivos com Git

Tags: php

Estou recrutando novos desenvolvedores para trabalhar em um projeto PHP, e existe um arquivo de configuração que contém todas as chaves dos bancos de dados dos meus clientes.

Como posso fazer para que esse novo desenvolvedor só tenha acesso a conexão a instância de desenvolvimento e não as de produção?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por parte.

Primeiro de tudo, não é interessante arquivos com dados sensíveis andar no versionamento, as configurações por exemplo poderiam ser feitas utilizando essa biblioteca: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

Agora, se os arquivos de configurações andam junto com o versionamento, talvez seja preciso você os separar. O arquivo de configuração para produção, ficaria por exemplo: `config/production.php`, este arquivo especifico você pode utilizar o `Git-Crypt`, sendo assim ele poderá criar o arquivo local de configuração, que este deverá estar no .gitignore e o de produção esta protegido, compartilhando a chave só com quem pode e com os servidores.

https://medium.com/trainingcenter/protegendo-dados-sens%C3%ADveis-com-git-crypt-9fca13e6835b

Comment: O que usar phpdotenv tem haver com separar os arquivos de configuração? Isso ficou confuso. A parte do .gitignore eu concordo, outra coisa legal seria uma "flag" pra ao invés puxar o arquivo de produção usaria uma versão para "desenvolvimento" com dados simples/comuns de autenticação, como localhost, root, etc.

Comment: A biblioteca phpdotenv facilita a captura de configurações de ambiente e utilizar na bilbioteca, ou até deixar arquivo de configurações de ambiente `.env` em produção, sem a necessidade de andar com arquivo de configurações no versionamento. Versionamento não é para isso.

Comment: Tá, mas não to falando de versionamento, e usar ou não phpdotenv não necessariamente tem relação com resolver o problema do autor da pergunta, mas a maneira que você escreveu leva a entender isto, o que pode confundir a cabeça dele, entende?

Comment: Sim, tem a resolver sim. Pois problema dele é arquivos de configuração em versionamento, o que a principio fere a proposta. Agora, essa biblioteca pode resolver sim a fonte do problema, agora, caso ele não queira, leia a resposta por completo que sugeri uma segunda alternativa.